# Allowing users to choose their role

Tags: wordpress

For a while now, I have been working on a registration form. In this register form, the user must be able to choose his or her role. I have been working on making this functional for a while, however, it will not work.

I have looked on StackOverflow to find people with the same problem as mine. I could not find many, and the few I did find, did not provide a good answer to my question or were left unanswered. I have also been looking for several other plugins that get the job done.

I tried two:

1. RegistrationMagic
2. Ultimate Member

Both did not work.

So my question is: Do you know how I can allow users to choose their role in Wordpress? Do you know any plugins that do this? If not, do you have any idea how I can reach this goal with UltimatePro or UserPro (not RegistrationMagic since it has been closed as of 6 February).
Hopefully, you guys can help me to make users choose a role.

Greetings,

Rezoo Aftib

Comment: guys please answer I really need to get this done.

Comment: hello and welcome to SO, please see how to provide minimal examples on asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, thank you. Can you help me with this question? I edited it

Comment: you need to add the code here on what have you tried and what are you planning to do and then any expert might be help you

Comment: @Prany I am using Wordpress, I have not coded anything